# Reading text file into a matrix in C

Tags: c

I have a text file that has 200 x 150 data in it (every number is separated with a space). I am trying to store these numbers into a matrix. My code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int i,j, matrix[200][150];

void getMatrix(){
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("PICTURE.txt", "r");
    char *line, *number;
    j = 0;
    while(!feof(file)){
        i = 0;
        fscanf(file, "%s", line);
        number = strtok(NULL, " ");
        while(number!= NULL){
            matrix[i][j] = atoi(number);
        }
        printf("\n");
        j++;
    }

}

void printMatrix(){
    int a, b;
    for(a=0; a<i; a++){
        for(b=0; b<j; b++){
            printf("%d", matrix[a][b]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(){
    getMatrix();
    printMatrix();
}
```

It prints out literally nothing. I don't understand why. How can I fix my code or do you have any other suggestions for rewriting it?

Comment: Do basic error checking and basic debugging. Check return value of all function calls like `fopen` and `fscanf`. Run your program in a debugger and step thru it line by line to see what it is doing and why the `printf` is not being called or not getting the right values.

Comment: At `fscanf(file, "%s", line);` there is no memory allocation for `line`.

Comment: `i` is never incremented. And using global variables like that is really bad practice as well.

Comment: `number = strtok(NULL, " ");` is incorrect, because the `NULL` tells `strtok` to continue working with a pointer that was previously passed at an initial call to `strtok`.

Comment: `while(number!= NULL)` how do you expect that loop to ever end considing `number` is never changed in the loop?

Comment: There are numerous errors in this code. Please also see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: If you had written a simpler program first, such as code to read a single (short) column of numbers, you would have discovered some of these bugs, and had a much easier time correcting them.

Comment: `fscanf(file, "%s", line);` will stop scanning at the first whitespace, so it make no sense to use `strtok` on it to extract a row of table data.

Comment: @WeatherVane that strtok usage will not work anyway :)

Comment: @0___________ funnily enough, I [noticed that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70626931/reading-text-file-into-a-matrix-in-c?noredirect=1#comment124852339_70626931).

Comment: I understand that there are numerous errors in this code. I can't debug that many errors. Maybe I should rewrite it from top to bottom but I am not sure how to (I am new in C).

Comment: By writing it one step at a time, and check that each step is correct before you move on. Write the `printMatrix` function before you write the `getMatrix` function (testing with initialised array values). Start with a small array too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a file, with 200x150 integer values (either on 200 lines, or all values on one line), then simply looping though the file with `fscanf()` reading and storing an integer at a time is all that is needed. You must validate each read and provide a way to communicate any failure within a function through the function return (or though a pointer updated within the function)

To begin, do not use *MagicNumbers* in your code and do not hardcode filenames. Instead, `#define` the constants you need (or use a global `enum`) and pass the open `FILE*` pointer to your read-function as a parameter after having opened (and validated that the file is open for reading) in the calling function. (If the file open fails -- there is no reason to make the read-function call to begin with)

In your case, you only have two needed constants:

```c
#define ROWS 200    /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define COLS 150
```

Do not use global variables unless absolutely necessary (there will be virtually no case where globals are needed when you begin learning C). Passing the matrix (2D array) as a parameter to your read-function, it can be written as:

```c
/* fill m[ROWS][COLS] with values read from fp.
 * returns 1 on success, 0 otherwise.
 */
int getmatrix (int (*m)[COLS], FILE *fp)
{
  for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
      if (fscanf (fp, "%d", &m[row][col]) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error reading m[%d][%d]\n", row, col);
        return 0;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return 1;
}
```

(**note:** how the return type for the function is `int` where `1` (true) is returned on success and `0` (false) is returned on failure. Also note that if 200x150 values are unable to be read, failure is returned)

Pass the filename to read from as the 1st argument to your program (that's what `int argc, char **argv` parameters to `main()` are for). Alternatively, you can prompt the user and read the filename as input. You can provide a fixed filename as a default value if no filename is entered (`stdin` is used as the default below), but otherwise do not hardcode filenames. You should not have to recompile your program simply to read from a different filename.

With those improvements made, your `main()` could be:

```c
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  
  int matrix[ROWS][COLS] = {{0}};   /* do not use global variables */
  /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
  FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

  if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading in caller */
    perror ("file open failed");
    return 1;
  }
  
  if (!getmatrix (matrix, fp)) {    /* pass array and open FILE*, validate */
    return 1;
  }
  fclose (fp);
  
  prnmatrix (matrix);       /* output results */
}
```

The complete program is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 200    /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define COLS 150

/* fill m[ROWS][COLS] with values read from fp.
 * returns 1 on success, 0 otherwise.
 */
int getmatrix (int (*m)[COLS], FILE *fp)
{
  for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
      if (fscanf (fp, "%d", &m[row][col]) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error reading m[%d][%d]\n", row, col);
        return 0;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return 1;
}

void prnmatrix (int (*m)[COLS])
{
  for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
      printf (col ? " %4d" : "%4d", m[row][col]);
    }
    putchar ('\n');
  }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  
  int matrix[ROWS][COLS] = {{0}};   /* do not use global variables */
  /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
  FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

  if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading in caller */
    perror ("file open failed");
    return 1;
  }
  
  if (!getmatrix (matrix, fp)) {    /* pass array and open FILE*, validate */
    return 1;
  }
  fclose (fp);
  
  prnmatrix (matrix);       /* output results */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

With 200 x 150 random values less than 10000 generated and written to `dat/int-200x150.txt`, you would run the program as:

```
$ ./bin/read2darrint dat/int-200x150.txt
9240 5939 3063 5789 7401 7869 4363 3321 7788 1008 7850 ...
2760 5263 5338 6390 8146  155  324  916 4489 3718 1616 ...
...
```

Where the output is 200 lines of 150 numbers each.

There are many ways to do this. One (better) way would be to loop reading each line of integer values as a string with `fgets()` and converting each set of ASCII digits into an integer value with `strtol()`. I say "better" in a sense that `strtol()` provides far better error reporting in the case of a failed conversion that the simple pass/fail that can be obtained from `fscanf()`.

The read before looping with `strtol()` would be with `fgets()` into a sufficiently sized buffer. That way if a *matching-failure* occurs, the error only impacts that line of data and no offending data is left in your input stream unread (as will occur with a *matching-failure* and `fscanf()`.

That said, with a properly formatted space-separated file full of data, there is nothing wrong with using `fscanf()` directly, just be aware there are more robust ways to do the read and conversion.

To use `strtol()`, to work through each line of values, you simply use a pointer to the beginning of each set of digits calling `strtol()` which then updates the `endptr` to one past the last digit converted allowing you to work your way though each number by updating the pointer (`nptr`) to `endptr` after each validated conversion. See [man 3 strtol](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html). You could updated the code above with:

```c
...
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>
...
#define MAXC 2048   /* (150 int + space) max of 1800 chars per-line */
```

and finally change your function to use `strtol()`, e.g.

```c
/* fill m[ROWS][COLS] with values read from fp.
 * returns 1 on success, 0 otherwise.
 */
int getmatrix (int (*m)[COLS], FILE *fp)
{
  char buf[MAXC];   /* buffer to hold each line */
  
  for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
    char *nptr = buf, *endptr = nptr;   /* nptr and endptr for strtol */
    
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {   /* read line of input */
      fprintf (stderr, "error: failed to read line %d\n", row);
      return 0;
    }
    
    for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
      errno = 0;                                  /* reset errno */
      long tmp = strtol (nptr, &endptr, 10);      /* convert w/strtol */
      
      if (nptr == endptr) { /* no ASCII digits coverted to a number */
        fputs ("error: no digits converted.\n", stderr);
        return 0;
      }
      else if (errno) { /* error in converstion, under/overflow */
        fputs ("error: under/overflow occurred in conversion.\n", stderr);
        return 0;
      }
      /* conversion outside range of int */
      else if (tmp < INT_MIN || INT_MAX < tmp) {
        fputs ("error: conversion out of range of integer.\n", stderr);
        return 0;
      }
      
      m[row][col] = tmp;   /* assign tmp to m[row][col] */
      nptr = endptr;       /* update nptr to endptr */
    }
  }
  
  return 1;
}
```

If an error occurs, you will know exactly what caused the failure. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Very clear and complete explanation, thank you very much I really appreciate it. One problem is that it is the first time I am using argc and argv so I am not very comfortable with them. I could not manage my PICTURE.txt file to pass into this code /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
  FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

Comment: You may need to pass the full path information to where `PICTURE.txt` is, e.g. `/path/to/PICTURE.txt` (if it isn't in the same directory you are running your program from). Now, one other issue may be if you created `PICTURE.txt` on windows using UTF-16 character set. UTF-8 is fine, but not UTF-16. You can determine that with the command `file /path/to/PICTURE.txt` and it will give you the encoding.

Comment: Also `argc` is just an `int` that tells you how my arguments (nul-terminated strings) are set in `argv`. `argv` is nothing but an array of pointers to strings (where the next pointer after the last argument is set to `NULL` as a sentinel). `argv[0]` is always the program name being run, so `argv[1]` is the first user-supplied argument.

Comment: warning: pointer type mismatch in conditional expression. That is the error I am getting. How pointer type mismatch because all of my text includes only integers? I mean it should always return an int

Comment: Show me the actual expression. There are few places a pointer mismatch can occur. If you want to simplify the filename passing and use `PICTURE.txt` as the default name if no argument is given, then do `FILE *fp = fopen (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "PICTURE.txt", "r");`

Comment: warning: pointer type mismatch in conditional expression
   FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : "PICTURE.txt";

Comment: Hah -- I thought so -- look at my last commend above this one `:)` `stdin` is already type `FILE*` so it is outside the `fopen()` statement, but when providing a default filename, the entire *ternary* operator goes inside `fopen (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "PICTURE.txt", "r");`

Comment: The *ternary* is just a `(test) ? if_true_clause : if_false_clase` A short-hand `if ... else ...` that can be used basically anywhere. It is very convenient used as a function parameter where you want to pass alternative values based on some test condition.

Answer (score 1):

Many problems:

- Never use `while(!feof(file)){`.  Instead check the return value of `fscanf(file, ...)`
- Do not use `"%s"` with out a width limit.
- Do not use pass `line` to a function without initializing/assigning it first.
- `i`  never incremented.
- `fclose(file)` when done.
- Check success of `fopen(...);`

---

GTG, maybe more later.

Comment: Why never use while(feof)?

Comment: Because after reading the last input the file-position indicator sits right before `EOF`, but has not yet attempted to read further. The next iteration begins. A read it attempted within the loop and fails triggering `EOF` -- but that comes too late and undefined behavior results when you attempt to use the variable you thought would be filled during that iteration....